# Using AwsSdkCall from C#

Tags: .net-core, aws-cdk

I want to create a Custom Resource in C#. In this resource I want to make an AwsSdkCall, something like this:

```c#
var sdkCall = new AwsSdkCall
{
    Service = "SSM",
    Action = "putParameter",
    Parameters = new PutParameters
    {
        Name = "/my-param",
        Tier = Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.ParameterTier.Standard,
        Type = Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.ParameterType.String,
        Value = "My value"
    }
};
```

The `Parameters` field is of type `object?`. I tried using an anonymous object here but I get an exception from JSII runtime that it can't handle anonymous objects. I tried to define my own class and use that, but JSII runtime didn't like that either.

What type am I supposed to use for this field to correctly specify parameters of the SDK call?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary for the Parameters.

```
Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{
  { "Name", "/my-param" },
  { "WithDecryption", true }
}
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.CustomResources.AwsSdkCall.html